# Image compression/decompression change file size

Tags: python, image, opencv, compression, hbase

I'm working on a project where I have to store tens of thousands of pictures every week into a hadoop cluster for later analysis. I'd like to store them into HBase and found this [nice pipeline](https://community.hortonworks.com/articles/218015/ingesting-binary-files-like-pdf-jpg-png-to-hbase-w.html) to do it. Before writing in HBase, I wrote a program that transforms the images into bytes and store them into a dataframe. The problem is that when I retrieve the images from the dataframe, the file size are bigger than the originals and I can't find the reason why.

The images I'm working with are around 50kB and saved as jpg format.
Here is the code to transform and store the data into a dataframe:

```
#list_files contain a list with all the files' paths
list_bytes=[] #list for images in bytes
for i in range (0, len(list_files)):
    image_original = cv2.imread(list_files[i]) #get the image i from the file list
    flatten = image_original.flatten() #flatten the array for compression
    compress = bz2.compress(flatten) #bzip into bytes
    image_64bytes = base64.b64encode(compress) #change it to 64bytes
    list_bytes.append(image_64bytes) 
df=pd.DataFrame({'file':list_files, 'bytes':list_bytes}) #write images into a dataframe along with their metadata
```

Now here is the code to retrieve an image from `df`:

```
decode = base64.b64decode(df.iloc[0,0])  #decode from 64bytes to bytes
unzip = bz2.decompress(decode) #unzip
conversion = np.frombuffer(unzip, dtype=np.uint8) #transform bytes into np.array
image_final = np.reshape(conversion, (650, 700,3)) #reshape image in its original format
```

To verify that `image_final` is identical to `image_original` the following should return an empty array:

```
print((np.where((image_original == image_final ) == False)))
```

> (array([], dtype=int64), array([], dtype=int64), array([],
> dtype=int64))

I then compared the size of the image in bytes stored in the dataframe and it seems that it is way bigger than the original one (50kB). I guess it is expected but it is still a big difference.

```
sys.getsizeof(df.iloc[0,0])
```

> 382129

Similarly if I save `image_final` on the disk with `cv2.imwrite(file_path, image_final)` the file is 80kB in jpg and 550kB in png. If `image_original` and `image_final` are identical why do they have a different size on the disk? This could definitely be a problem later when all the images will be loaded for analysis.

Thank you in advance for your help

Note: I also tried to use `cv2.imencode('.png', image_original)[1] / cv2.imdecode(conversion, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)` instead of `image_original.flatten() / np.reshape(conversion, (650, 700,3))` but the results are quite similar.

Comment: The first question is what are the images like? Are they like photographs with noise and variations in colour and lighting, or are they computer-generated and cartoon-like with blocks of solid colour. As a simple rule, if the former, you should store in JPEG. If the latter, you should store in PNG. `bz2` compression is not going to help much with photograph-like images and base64 encoding is always going to make things worse. Why don't you store JPEGs as JPEGs and PNGs as PNGs - that's the best way to store things - by design.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I thought about it and realized I could just read the file as bytes and save them into the dataframe. No more change in size.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of loading the image and convert it into bytes, it is possible to just read the files as bytes and save them into the dataframe:

```
# list_files contain a list with all the files' paths
list_bytes=[]
for i in range (0, len(list_files)):
    in_file = open(list_files[i], "rb") # opening for [r]eading as [b]inary
    data = in_file.read() #insert bytes data into data
    compress = bz2.compress(data) #compress the data in bytes
    to_64bytes = base64.b64encode(compress) #change bytes to bytes64
    to_str = to_64bytes.decode() #transform as string for storage
    in_file.close()
    list_bytes.append(to_str) 
df=pd.DataFrame({'file':list_files, 'bytes':list_bytes}) #write it into a database with metadata
```

Then to read the images:

```
s = df.iloc[0,1] #cell containing the string of the data to retrieve

decode = base64.b64decode(s) #transforms to byte64
unzip = bz2.decompress(decode) #unzip
conversion = np.frombuffer(unzip, dtype=np.uint8) #transform into np.array
img = cv2.imdecode(conversion, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR) #transform into img

plt.imshow(img)
plt.show()
```

---

<sub>This answer was posted as an [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/53341208/2) to the question [Image compression/decompression change file size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53341208/image-compression-decompression-change-file-size) by the OP [JeremyJJ](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10663476/jeremyjj) under CC BY-SA 4.0.</sub>